# Android Emulator perpetually shows "Unfortunately, Google Play services has stopped."

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am using Android Studio and set my run configuration to run in an emulator as per the following in the AVD Manager:

- Device Definition: Nexus 5X
- System Image: Release Name - Lollipop API level - 22 ABI - x86 Target - Android 5.1

Upon  starting the emulated device, it issues a barrage of messages, including:
"Unfortunately, Google Play Services has stopped"; and
"Unfortunately, Google Maps has stopped"

It seems to add these to some kind of buffer because if I relentlessly click on OK it eventually clears them but the frequency of notifications is unmanageable as I cannot select anything else on the phone.

Any clues as to how I can stop these notifications from showing up in the first place, at startup without having to start the device and alter a few settings thereafter?

Comment: Post your Logcat error logs